# Python Quicksort algorithm is sorting incorrectly

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

As the title reads, I'm having encountering an error with my Python Quicksort code. My code is further below and this is the input file that I'm using to test.

```
5
3
8
6
7
4
9
2
1
10
```

In the code, the variable `i` is the border value and the variable `j` is the current value being compared to the pivot. The issue is that when `Partition` executes its first iteration, the value `3` in the array doesn't end up on the left side of the pivot value (`5` in this case) as it should. I'm always using the leftmost index as the pivot by the way.

```
def Partition(input_array, left_index, right_index):
    pivot_value = input_array[left_index]

    i = left_index + 1
    for j in range(i+1, right_index):
        if input_array[j] < pivot_value:
            swap(input_array, i, j)
            i = i + 1

    swap(input_array, left_index, i - 1)
    print(input_array)
    return i - 1

def swap(input_array, i, j):
    input_array[i], input_array[j] = input_array[j], input_array[i]
    return input_array
```

This is the array *before* the first iteration of `Partition`:

```
5, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4, 9, 2, 1, 10
```

This is the array *after* the first iteration of `Partition`:

```
1, 4, 2, 5, 7, 3, 9, 8 , 6, 10
```

As you can see, the `3` is in the incorrect spot. Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ Step through the program, look at the variables and see where it goes wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start `for j` loop from `i+1` index, algorithm does not discover that `3<5` and does not advance `i` index. Remove `+1`

Refer to [Lomuto scheme here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme)

Comment: I noticed this not long after. Thank you, sir!